# Describe a man standing right side of me

Tags: idioms, phrases

[image: I want describe the man standing.]

Assume that I am the person who is wearing white with blue shoes. I want to describe the man standing next to me.
i.e:

> standing right to me

or

> standing in front of me..

like that.

Comment: The picture is rather small on my screen. Which pair's blue - the pair with the white toes or the pair with the dark toes?

Comment: Either way, you can say that he's standing *next to* you. Or are you trying to say that they are standing almost at right angles to each other?

Comment: _"The man is standing at my right."_

Comment: @Lawrence. the pair with white toe. yes standing right angles.

Answer (score 1):

Any of these are fine, and mean the same thing:

- > Standing to my right
- > Standing on my right
- > Standing at my right
- > Standing to the right of me

> Standing in front of me

is correct as well, but

> Standing right to me

is not.